# NullPointerException in pre-launch report

Tags: android, google-play, firebase-test-lab, prelaunch

I am now having several failures in the google-play pre-launch report. But I am not sure what to do about this as I do not have the crashing part under control.
[image]

This is the stacktrace

```
 FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 Process: com.google.android.apps.docs, PID: 12587
 java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.google.android.apps.docs.shareitem.UploadSharedItemActivityDelegate.a(UploadSharedItemActivityDelegate.java:352)
    at com.google.android.apps.docs.shareitem.UploadSharedItemActivityDelegate.b(UploadSharedItemActivityDelegate.java:315)
    at gm.run(BaseActivity.java:236)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5097)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:785)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:601)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Seems to affect Motorola mainly:

[image]

Comment: `BaseActivity.java` is your code? What's around line 236?

Comment: No this is not in my code - I suspect it is in Drives code